# Facebook dialog

Tags: facebook, dialog, popup

Hi i want the facebook popup dialog , kidnly don't suggest me fancybox/lightbox or other 3rd party script to show this type of facebook dialog i need some official facebook script to call the popup dialog.

i have searched many forums and official facebook doc but im unable to find any solution.

URL of popup dialog sample https://www.facebook.com/SAJJADALIOFFICIAL/app_375422485813449 (click Yellow button with Join Crowd to view the dialog)

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The first dialog is not an "official dialog", it's their dialog, it is only wrapped in a facebook dialog box.

You can use the [Fb.Dialog.create method](http://fbdevwiki.com/wiki/FB.Dialog) to show that kind of dialog with your own content.
That's not part of the official documentation, but it works none the less.
Keep in mind that the style of that content is up to you, for example in the url you posted, if you inspect the dialog you'll see that the css is not from the facebook cdn servers but of *ustream.tv*.

Once you click the *"Join with Facebook"* button an "official dialog" pops out, and that is using the [FB.login method](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.login/).